# Issue with calling a public method from a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I am trying to create a website login which will read usernames and passwords from a textfile. I'm using a glassfish server and I am running this code from NetBeans on Chrome. The HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error give "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException" as the exception. The issue seems to be caused from were I declare the string pass, as when I remove this line of code and replace the variable in the if statement to any string the login work fine. I tried using this line of code in a mainmethod java class and it works perfectly so the connection to the textfile is working as it should be. I've been struggling with little bit of code for the past few hours and I'm not getting anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
<%@page import="dao.UserDAO"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        String username=request.getParameter("username");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        
          UserDAO mDAO= new UserDAO();
          String pass= (mDAO.getUserLogin(username).getPassword());
                
          
        if((password.equals(pass)))
            {
            session.setAttribute("username",username);
            response.sendRedirect("adminhome.jsp");
            }
        else
            response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

The request parameters are working fine. This works perfectly as long as the password matches, so they are being passed.

```
<%
    String username=request.getParameter("username");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");


    if((password.equals("john")))
        {
        session.setAttribute("username",username);
        response.sendRedirect("adminhome.jsp");
        }
    else
        response.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");
    %>
```

Comment: Where are your HTML elements with the names `username` and `password`?

Comment: @DrewKennedy Probably username and password - the request parameters

Comment: @DrewKennedy They are textboxes on a Login jsp page. They seem to be coming through fine for me though. –

Comment: @JoshuaSmith Okay - just making sure they have the correct attribute because I'm not seeing them in the code provided. That *would* throw your NPE.